# Recaptcha not rendering in lightbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lightbox, recaptcha

I've implemented reCAPTCHA following the instructions on this site:

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

However I am unable to get it to render on my lightbox. It renders as below when i check with firebug.

```
<noscript> &lt;iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lctg74SAAAAADV4UAfyRdEUdZi_FGc4PCqA7LEn" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;/iframe&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;input name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" type="hidden" /&gt; </noscript>
```

Note that when i look in firebug the < and > display as the text "& lt;" and "& gt;" (without the space)

Let me know if there's any additional information required to help with this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How are you assigning the output of the Html Helper to the fancybox?  Could you post your code?  It's just a guess, but if are you using the `<%: Html.GenerateCaptcha() %>` syntax, try the `<%= Html.GenerateCaptcha()` %> syntax.